# Session Not Carrying Over Links

Tags: php, url, session, hyperlink

I have login code which if you type the url 'logout.php' it logs you out.
But if you click the link pointing to logout.php it doesn't actually log you out.

At the same time if I then type /settings.php it shows you the settings page.
But the link that goes to /settings.php asks you to login again.

$session_start is on every page, it just seems odd that the url works but the links do not?

Comment: You should post some code :)

Comment: $session_start or session_start() ?

Comment: Sorry,
Each 'secured' page starts
'<?php
session_start();'

The Logout page Contains:
'<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();'

In IE it moves pages and logs out via link and url

In Chrome & FF It Only Works Via Url and not links - never experienced anything like this before